# Get the current step number in a gym.Env

Tags: python, openai-gym, stable-baselines

Is there a way to access the current step number of a `gym.Env` from inside its `step` method?

I'm using a model from `stable_baselines3` and want to terminate the env when N steps have been taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own `TerminatingEnv` class that wraps an enviroment and takes into account counting and terminating if the count is too high internally, so you can use it like any other environment while still having the terminatiion feature. `env.step_counter` will tell you how many steps have been done since the reset of the enviroment:

```
import gym

class TerminatingEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, env, max_steps):
        self.env = env
        self.max_steps = max_steps
        self.step_counter = 0

    def step(self, action):
        
        obs, reward, terminated, truncated, info = self.env.step(action)
        self.step_counter += 1
        if self.step_counter >= self.max_steps:
            return obs, reward, True, True, info
        else:
            return obs, reward, terminated, truncated, info
    
    def reset(self):
        self.step_counter = 0
        return self.env.reset()
    
    def render(self):
        return self.env.render()
    
    def close(self):
        return self.env.close()
    
    def seed(self, seed=None):
        return self.env.seed(seed)
    

env0 = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env = TerminatingEnv(env0, 5)
while True:
    action = 1
    env.reset()
    for i in range(100):
        obs, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)
        print(env.step_counter)
        if terminated:
            break
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1
```

And so on...

In older versions, `self.env.step` returns 4 values and not 5, so maybe you will have to adapt that.

Answer (score 0):

You can end simulation before its done with TimeLimit wrapper:

```
from gymnasium.wrappers import TimeLimit
```

the wrapper rather calls env.step() and updates ’truncated’ flag, using
current step number and max_episode_steps (which can be specified in
env.make()) before returning: obs,reward,... (as shown in the source: https://gymnasium.farama.org/_modules/gymnasium/wrappers/time_limit/#TimeLimit)

below is an example of how to use the wrapper, gymnasium version 1.26.4 (please replace the environment with one installed in gym, env.render() is redundante):

```
env = gym.make('GridWorld-v0', render_mode="human")
# add a time limit (max steps per espiode) to cutoff
# simulation if the goal isn't hit
env = TimeLimit(env, max_episode_steps=10)  
# 2nd param opt (see register)
print('max eps steps, ', env.spec.max_episode_steps)
state = env.reset()
env.render()
done = False
while not done:
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    state, reward, done, truncated, info = env.step(action)
    env.render()
    if truncated: 
        break
else:
    print("[info] simulation terminated, mission accomplished!")
if truncated:
    print("[info] simulation truncated, mission failed!”)
```

the output maybe:

```
...
max eps steps,  10
...
[info] simulation truncated, mission failed!
```